# How to recover deleted data in alfresco share through java?

Tags: spring, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new to alfresco community and i am using alfresco community for Document Management System.

Now my problem is i have deleted one document like as shown below and now i want to recover that data into same in which folder that exist before deletion

```
Document document = (Document) session.getObjectByPath(filePath);
document.delete();
```

Please any body help me...

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using? (Newer recovery APIs won't be in older versions so it matters)

Comment: I have been using alfresco community 5.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
nodeArchiveService.restoreArchivedNode(NodeRef archivedNodeRef)
```

To get the archivedNodeRef you can either search it in alfresco database (bad) find it using one of it property under the archive://SpacesStore

```
new NodeRef(archiveRoot.getStoreRef(),(String)node.get("UUID"))
```

http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/node/archive/NodeArchiveService.html

If you have the trashcanCleaner up and running, your trashcan is protected 14d by default after that, the node is removed.

An sql query to get node from archive store:

```
String sql = "SELECT n.id, n.UUID "
            + "FROM alf_node n, alf_store s "
            + "WHERE n.store_id = s.id "
            + "AND s.protocol = 'archive' "
            + "AND n.AUDIT_MODIFIED is not null "
            + "ORDER BY n.id asc ";
```

Add a few criteria in the where clause on the ALF_NODE_PROPERTIES table and you are set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java api VersionService(restore), if you know the deleted node.

**http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/deleted-nodes/{id}/restore**

restore
@Auditable(parameters={
"nodeRef",
"parentNodeRef",
"assocTypeQName",
"assocQName"
})
NodeRef restore(NodeRef nodeRef,
NodeRef parentNodeRef,
QName assocTypeQName,
QName assocQName)
By default a deep restore is performed.
Parameters:
nodeRef - the node reference to a node that no longer exists in the store
parentNodeRef - the new parent of the restored node
assocTypeQName - the assoc type qname
assocQName - the assoc qname
Returns:
the newly restored node reference

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your node had "sys:temporary" aspect applied, then you are out of luck, that's the equivalent of "shift + delete" in Windows. You could still get it's content from the deleted store on disk, though.

Take a look at this blog post to understand the complete process:
https://blyx.com/2014/08/18/understanding-alfresco-content-deletion/